# Using one .htaccess file in root for several domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an OpenCart multistore installation which is why I have several domains pointing into the same server folder. In this folder I have an `.htaccess` file which I only get to work for one of the domains (in this case: `city-gardener.com`).

Here is the code:

```bsh
# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# append WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L=301]

# delete trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ https://www.city-gardener.com/$1 [R,L=301]

# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.city-gardener.com/$1 [R,L=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=off

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
#RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(?:(?:(\w{2})(?:/|\z))?(?:/|\z)?)?(?:([^?]*))? index.php?_route_=$2&site_language=$1 [L,QSA]
```

How would I have to change this so that it works for other domains just the same? I know I somehow need to replace the hard-coded domain with something like `{HTTP_HOST}` but I always end up having several `www.`s in my URL or similar errors. Would be great if someone could help out!

Comment: What are the example URLs for this it doesn't work?

Comment: One domain is the city-gardener.com domain and the other one is a .de-Domain (diestadtgaertner.de)

Answer (score 0):

You have set wrong flags: `[R,L=301]` rather than `[R=301,L]`, your URL was rewritten multiple times and you've got several `www` added.

To get rid of explicitly specified domain names, modify your rules like this

```
# delete trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi umka, thanks for the answer. Still it doesn't work with that one either. The problem is that I don't know how to adapt the htaccess in order to get rid of the domain name that's currently included.